# How can we make the NSTimer to run in background for my audio player in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am making a audio player in iOS and i have made the audio player,and i am updating the duration of currently playing song using NSTimer,but the thing is that if my app goes in background the timer stops .

Is there any way by which i can run my NSTimer in background ,in order to update the currently playing song current duration.
How apple is running their Audio player in background?

MPMediaPlayer and AVQueuePlayer progress slider, with time left and time elapsed.

Comment: When your view is loaded againg. You can update your NSTimmer in ViewWillAppear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is in the background, nobody will see the update anyway.

Just make sure you start the timer again when the app is coming into the foreground, and you'll be fine.

Comment: then how i'll i keep track of the timer when the application comes into foreground.

Comment: your media player should have the current playtime, so just get that and set it in the slider, then start up the timer again

Comment: Thanks i got that...using current playbacktime

Comment: @TheEye How to show time label according to the music player, now playing song. Please elaborate that part too. Thanks.

Comment: @HDdeveloper that is quite easy,i think you can get that with the MPMediaItem object